# Image beside text with more than 2 lines android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to display an image next to last alphabet of a text ?

i got a problem when having a textview with more than 1 lines, the image wont follow the last alphabet of the text

The output that I should make should be like number 1 and number 2,  but my output just be like number 1 and number 3 (image below)

[image]

*I tried to make my explanation clear so I make it with png to figure what I mean.

To make the correct output, what I should do on my XML ? or I should go with additional programming code in java. please help, thanks

Comment: Can you please show your XML code of how are you creating test with 2 lines once?? Are you using 2 textviews?

Answer (score 0):

I might try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLine1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="12sp"
    android:text="Username of" />
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLine2"
    android:layout_below="@id/textLine1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="12sp"
    android:text="a man" />

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="12sp"
    android:layout_height="12sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textLine1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textLine2"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So yeah this will help. And as you can I haven't use `android:layout_marginTop` attribute here but if you use it make sure it's the same for `textLine2` and `iamge` so that it would look good. And if you want to add more such name with images just copy -paste the same code below it and simply change their `android:id`.

Also change the id here in this line: `android:layout_below="@+id/textLine1"`
So that new views will be added below the previous once.
If you need more clarification please drop a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView27"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/star"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Username" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:text="Testing my  \n text for images"
    />
```

and in your java code:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
                       builder.append("Testing for text view \n and images")
                               .append(" ", new ImageSpan(getActivity(), R.drawable.com_facebook_button_icon), 0)
                               .append(" ");


 myTextview.setText(builder);
```

[image: Result:]